# How to split an expression into an array?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to convert an expression string into arrays. For string `(10+2)/33`, the expected result is `['(', '10', '+', '2', ')', '/', '33']`. There maybe some spaces between them, and the valid operators are `+-*/()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
"(10+2)/33".split(/\b|(?!\d)/)
```

(Obviously, the goal here is to split the string, not to check if characters are allowed).

The idea is to use the fact that `(`, `)`, `+`, `-`, `/`, `*` are single characters that are not in the `\w` character class. So `\b` will match when a digit is followed by one of these characters and vice versa. `(?!\d)` *(negative lookakead: not followed by a digit)*, since it is the second alternative, is like `\B(?!\d)` and will match between two signs.

If you want to deal with eventual spaces, you only need to add `\s*` in each branch:

```
"(10+2)/33".split(/\s*\b\s*|\s*(?!\d)/)
```

Note that it may generate an empty item at the begining.

To avoid the problem you can use the `scan` method with a different pattern:

```
" ( 2 (10+2) / 33) ".scan(/\G\s*\K(?:\d+|\S)/)
```

Where `\G` ensures that all matches are contiguous from the start of the string and `\K` discards all on the left from the match result (the eventual white-spaces).

Comment: I can do result_array.compact to remove spaces. Thank  you!

Answer (score 0):

```
"(10 + 2) / 33".delete(" ").split(/(\D)/).reject(&:empty?)
# => ["(", "10", "+", "2", ")", "/", "33"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `scan` function also.

```
> s = "(10+2)/33"
> s.scan(/\d+|[^\s\w]/)
=> ["(", "10", "+", "2", ")", "/", "33"]
> s.scan(/\d+|[^\s\d]/)
=> ["(", "10", "+", "2", ")", "/", "33"]
```